# VSTS Build Definitions for Solutions with multiple web projects

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ms-release-management

I have visual studio solution with 2 web projects. The source is in VSTS and the apps are hosted in Azure. I have build and release management setup to automatically deploy to Azure.

So every time I check in something, 2 releases are triggered, one for each web project. Is there any way I can separate the two? The web project should only trigger for a check in on that folder and the api trigger for a check in on that folder?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? What do your CI triggers look like?

Comment: I have both web projects under the solution folder. CI triggers is on the main solution folder. It generates 2 zip files one for each web project. But that means for a single change both web projects are deployed. What I want is to have 2 build and release definitions and only deploy when a check in happens on that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change Path filters for specific path of each web project path. More information, you can refer to [Build definition triggers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers).

Comment: What I tried was to create a build definition per project. In each project's repository tab I cloak the folder for the other project. But I was getting no output. I guess what you are saying is to instead add an exclude path in the triggers tab?

Comment: @BeesNees Yes I mean triggers tab. Regarding no output issue, you can add MSBuild arguments: /p:OutputPath=”bin\$(BuildConfiguration); More information, you can check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897988/build-separately-a-web-app-backend-in-a-xamarin-solution-using-vsts

Comment: I will try adding the additional trigger. The no output issue is only when I cloak the 2nd project. Otherwise I get the zip file output.

Comment: @BeesNees The trigger is used for CI build (changes trigger build), you still need to have two build definitions and change trigger for each web project. You can cloak a project or just map the target project to build agent. Regarding release, change artifact to link to corresponding build definition.